# Calling to a pointer from a c++ thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, vb6

I'm trying to call from a thread to a pointer.
Here is my code:

myDll.dll c++ :

```
long cbAddrAsync;
void _asyncer(void* data)
{
        typedef void (__stdcall *FUNCPTR)();
    FUNCPTR vbFunc;
    vbFunc = (FUNCPTR)cbAddrAsync;
    vbFunc();
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void async(long addr)
{
    cbAddrAsync = addr;
    HANDLE hHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthread(_asyncer,0,NULL);
}
```

calling to this extern with vb6:
In Module1:

```
Declare Sub async Lib "myDll.dll" (ByVal addr As Long)
Sub onAsync()
MsgBox "ASYNC"
End Sub
```

In Form1:

```
Private Sub Command_Click()
Call async(AddressOf Module1.onAsync)
End Sub
```

when i click at command button , The problem occurs in

```
dll:
Unhandled exception at 0x734f9232 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000076.
in vbFunc();
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: To format code properly in questions, just indent the code lines with at least 4 whitespaces.

Comment: You need much more than `_beginthread` to create a create a thread to run VB code. It requires something called thread local storage which needs to be setup and you CAN NOT access any UI and most common/shared data. Even API calls require TLS unless they are decalred in a type library. Check out http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/Multi_threading

Comment: Easiest way would be in `_asyncer` to create an instance of a public VB6 created class. You'll need to use `CoInitialize` and `CoCreateInstance` passing VB6 class CLSID on the new thread.  This will initialize VB6 run-time (including TLS, etc.) so you can call your `AddressOf` callback and use all VB6 built-in functions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x00000076 is an invalid memory address. All addresses under 0x0000ffff are invalid. This catches a whole class of errors (failed memory allocations or object creation) along the lines of 0x0 and 0x0 + 2 (or 0x0 + 0x76) etc. The errors are errors that programmers are supposed to check for but often don't.

My guess is you are accessing the 0x76th byte of a structure that wasn't initialised.

VB6 is designed to be a COM server not a dynamic load dll.

AddressOf has rules because you are actually calling VB6 runtime not your program.

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called Symbols in C:\

Start Windbg. File menu - Symbol File Path and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

```
windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat
```

You can press `F12` to stop it and `kb` will show the call stack (`g` continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.

Type `lm` to list loaded modules, `x *!*` to list the symbols and `bp symbolname` to set a breakpoint

If programming in VB6 then this environmental variable `link=/pdb:none` stores the symbols in the dll rather than seperate files. Make sure you compile the program with **No Optimisations** and tick the box for **Create Symbolic Debug Info**. Both on the **Compile** tab in the **Project's Properties**.

Also CoClassSyms (microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) can make symbols from type libraries.